# SSRS reporting tool and X++ code for MS Dynamics D365

Tags: reporting-services, x++, erp, dynamics-365-operations

I am doing a SSRS Report for MS Dynamics D365 for report layout. I have successfully mapped the correct field in the line level. I have 3 lines in the line level, the first line of one of the field have a data or a value and the next other 2 does not have a value. After i mapped and wrote some codes in the DP Class and produce the layout, the field is repeating on the next line. I dont want the  field to repeat to the next line. Please help. Thanks

[report layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynFCN.png)

The code:

MGAItemInfo is the field. Using X++ code

```
  select MGAItemInfo from purchline where purchline.PurchId == _purchaseOrderHeader.PurchId 
            purchLine.ItemId == purchPurchaseOrderTmp.ItemId  
           purchline.InventTransId == purchPurchaseOrderTmp.PurchLineInventTransId;


PurchPurchaseOrderTmp.MGAItemRemark = purchline.MGAItemInfo;
```

[report design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkDIP.png)

Expect not to repleat the fields on everyline in the line level, But the kine is repeat on the next line.

Comment: Move that expression to outside your MGAItemName rowgroup. You might have to create another parent rowgroup to achieve this. At the moment it's within the MGAItemName rowgroup so it will repeat with every instance of whatever that rowgroup is grouped by.

Comment: Thanks so much, It works!!!! :) No more repeat!!!